# getting null value from textarea if it contain \n

Tags: java, null, jtextarea

I have one JTextArea from which I am getting a value and using it for further purpose. It's working fine.

But if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (`\n`) in starting while entering text in JTextArea then I get `null`. I don't understand why this happening.

I am getting the value from JTextArea using the following code. (*I know it's simple*.)

```
input = txtInput.getText().toString();
```

Please give me any reference. I think this one line of code and description is sufficient to understand this question.

Answer (score 0):

That may help you

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText()

using `txtInput.getText()` is the same than using `txtInput.getDocument().getText(offset,length)`

Said that.

When you create a new JTextArea, it does nothing.

```
public JTextArea() {
    this(null, null, 0, 0);
}
```

but when you modify the information in the textArea it initializes the Document, unless you create the JTextArea with this constructor

```
public JTextArea(Document doc, String text, int rows, int columns)
```

That's why you receive a NullPointer.